# Views theming: How to grab the contextual filter?

Tags: views, theming

My setup is really simple. I have a taxonomy view that takes two contextual filters:

- Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
- Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

Due to a new request I need to be able to change the footer of the view based on the contextual filter. Since the contextual filter isn't inside the [fields] array of the view how can I access its value in my template file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality in views itself

- In footer add a global text area
- Select PHP code in the text format select box
- Enter the following code

  ```
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  /* $view->args will contain all the argument values in the order */
  ```

However make sure to include php opening and closing tags and read [this](http://drupal.org/node/489748#comment-1694914) one if you have multiple views in same page.

Comment: Thanks. With $view->args I can get the tid of the term. The link you provided seems very useful since my view is actually an attachment to another view. That probably saved me a few hours. Cheers